# Regex to split string with one or more space and preserve them

Tags: java, regex, string, split

For example this string: `"This      is my    example     "`

I want to split it into: `["This", "      ", "is", " ", "my", "    ", "example", "     "]`

Right now I am using the look ahead and look back regex to preserve the spaces:

`string.split("(?<=\\s+)|(?=\\s+)"))`

but it is splitting on every single space:

`["This", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "is", " ", "my", ...]`

How do you write up a regex that splits on and preserve the chunk of spaces?

Comment: It should be [`s.split("(?<=\\S)(?=\\s)|(?<=\\s)(?=\\S)")`](https://regex101.com/r/znORmR/1)

Comment: Sweet @WiktorStribiżew that works!